# Which is right on number agreement?

Tags: dialect

> "And what are Slytherin and Hufflepuff?"  "School houses. (1)
>   **There's** four. Everyone says Hufflepuff (2) **are** a lot o' duffers, but --"  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

I guess, *there’re* is grammatically proper instead of (1)-there’s; but I’m not sure for (2)-are. Because *are* can be used except when Hufflepuff is regarded as a collective noun, I think. Would you let me know how to use the verb grammatically right?

Comment: This is a question of dialect. (1) _There's four_ is the way native Anglophones use the language. Of course it's grammatically incorrect, but it's idiomatic spoken & informal written English: idiom (oil) & grammar (water) don't mix. (2) _Everyone says Hufflepuff **are** a lot o' duffers_ is unexceptional in British English, but it'd more than likely not be said or written in American English. We'd say _Everyone says Hufflepuff **is/has** a lot of duffers_. It's a Q of how one perceives Hufflepuff: as a singular collective (use **is**) or a collection of individuals (use **are**). Both are OK.

Comment: @Bill Franke: It's not obvious to me that *there's = there are* is any more "grammatically incorrect" than *ain't = **am** not*, as in *"I ain't convinced"*.

Comment: @Fumble: If you get a choice on the IELTS between "**There's** ten men in the room" & "**There are** ten men in the room", the correct answer is clear: "**There are**". What's _grammatically correct_ is based on the standard dialect, which means the prestige dialect, which means the dialect that's tested by the TOEFL, TOEIC, & IELTS. They don't test for knowledge of local, regional, or substandard dialects. I don't teach local, regional, or substandard dialects except to explain that stuff like "There's 10 men in the room" & "I ain't misbehavin'" are idiomatic somewhere or other & informal.

Comment: @Fumble: And don't forget that my prime concern is with **formal written prose** (standardized English tests, academic journals, high-quality books that actually get copy edited, dissertations & theses, & perhaps the business reports in a few companies around the world), because that's the only linguistic arena that comes with style manuals & rules galore. The spoken language & the informal written language is much like the Roman Colosseum in its Lions versus the Christians heyday: bloody awfully unregulated & grammatically gory ("Murder most foul, as in the best it is.").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the answers for [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-therere-similar-to-theres-a-correct-contraction), *there's* is often used in spoken English to mean *there are*.

*Hufflepuff* (which is the name of a school house) is used in that sentence to mean all the people who go to that school.